# Поиск минимального остова(Алгоритм Краскалла)

Tags: java, алгоритм

Пытаюсь реализовать следующий алгоритм:
Алгоритм Краскалла

```
1. Сначала упорядочиваем все ребра по возрастанию весов.
2.  Заводим таблицу: в левой колонке список ребер, в правой компоненты связности.
3.  В первой строчке список ребер пустой и все компоненты связности одновершинные. Берем минимальное по стоимости (по весу) ребро 
включаем его в список ребер. Соответствующие две вершины объединяем
в одну компоненту связности.
4.  Берем следующее по стоимости (весу) ребро, добавляем к содержимому предыдущей строчки левого столбца; объединяем компоненты
связности. Если концы ребра уже принадлежат одной и той же
компоненте связности, то данное ребро в состав минимального остова
не включается.
5.  Повторяем эти операции до тех пор, пока все вершины не окажутся в одной единственной компоненте связности (для этого потребуется
включить в состав остова ровно n-1 ребро).
```

Но в итоге у меня в список добавляется лишнее ребро 1-2
не могу реализовать алгоритм, может кто какую идею подаст?
вот код:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

private static LinkedHashMap<int[], Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap();

private static LinkedHashMap<int[], Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
private static ArrayList<int[]> ribs = new ArrayList();

public static void main(String[] arg){
    //Добавляю ребра и их вес в map
    map.put(new int[]{1, 7}, 1);
    map.put(new int[]{1, 2}, 20);
    map.put(new int[]{2, 7}, 4);
    map.put(new int[]{2, 3}, 5);
    map.put(new int[]{3, 7}, 9);
    map.put(new int[]{4, 7}, 16);
    map.put(new int[]{5, 7}, 25);
    map.put(new int[]{4, 5}, 17);
    map.put(new int[]{3, 4}, 3);
    map.put(new int[]{1, 6}, 23);
    map.put(new int[]{6, 7}, 36);
    map.put(new int[]{5, 6}, 28);
    System.out.println("Не отсортированная:");
    showMap(map);
    Iterator<Map.Entry<int[], Integer>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); // итератор на начальный map
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(); // список весов ребер
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<int[], Integer> entry = iterator.next();
        list.add(entry.getValue()); // добавляю вес ребер в список ребер
    }
    Collections.sort(list); // сортирую список весов ребер
//буферные переменные
    int buf = 0;
    int[] bufKey;
    int bufValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { // сортируем map по весам и кладем значение в sortedMap
        Iterator<Map.Entry<int[], Integer>> iterator2 = map.entrySet().iterator();
        buf = list.get(i);//вес из списка весов отсортированных по возрастанию
        while (iterator2.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<int[], Integer> entry = iterator2.next();
            bufKey = entry.getKey();     //Ключи(Ёбрышки)
            bufValue = entry.getValue(); //значения(веса)
            if (buf == bufValue) {// если ключ(вес) в исходной мапе совпадает с весм из списка, то добавляем пару
                // вес - ребро в сортированную map
                sortedMap.put(bufKey, bufValue);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Отсортированная:");
    showMap(sortedMap);// вывод в минимального остова
    search(sortedMap); // поиск минимального остова

    for (int[] x : ribs) { // отображение ребер входящих в минимальный остов
        showRib(x);
    }

}

private static void showMap(LinkedHashMap<int[], Integer> map){ // отображение map
    for (Map.Entry<int[], Integer> pair : map.entrySet()){
        int[] rib = pair.getKey();
        int weight = pair.getValue();
        System.out.print("(");
        for (int j = 0; j < rib.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(rib[j] + " - ");
        }
        System.out.println("\b\b\b) : " + weight);
    }
}

private static void search(LinkedHashMap<int[], Integer> map){ // поиск минимального остова
    int[] buf;
    for (Map.Entry<int[], Integer> pair : map.entrySet()){
        if (ribs.size() == 0){ // если список ребер минимального остова пуст, добавить первое ребро из map
            ribs.add(buf = pair.getKey());
        }else if (!check(buf = pair.getKey())){ // иначе добавить ребро после проверки на его вхождение
            ribs.add(buf);
        }
    }
}
private static boolean check(int[] rib) { // проверка ребра на вхождение в состав минимального остова
    boolean flagX = false, flagY = false;

    //если оба флага установлнены в true, значит ребро состоит из вершин, которые входят в состав минимального
    // отова и не подходит для его включения в остав

    for (int[] x : ribs) { // перебор ребер уже входящих в состав
        if(x[1] == rib[0]){ // если вторая вершина ребра входящего в состав ребра совпадает с первой вершиной
            // проверемого ребра, установить флаг
            flagX = true;
        }
        if(x[1] == rib[1]){// если вторая вершина ребра входящего в состав ребра совпадает с второй вершиной
            // проверемого ребра, установить флаг
            flagY = true;
        }
    }
    return flagX && flagY;
}
private static void showRib(int[] rib){ // вывод ребра в консоль
    for (int i = 0; i < rib.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(rib[i] + " - ");
    }
    System.out.println("\b\b\b");
}
```

}
//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном коде нет проверки условия "Если концы ребра уже принадлежат одной и той же
компоненте связности", а ребро добавляется безусловно просто тогда, когда его вес найден.

Может быть, поможет [простая реализация с e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/mst_kruskal)

Кроме того, неразумно хранить ребра с весом и ещё раз веса отдельно, и потом искать - разве нельзя список ребер отсортировать по ключу веса?

Comment: Это поможет в случае, если веса будут разные, а если у нас есть несколько ребер с одним весом, например 5?
Тогда в map будет сохранено только одно значение, так как все ключи должны быть уникальные

Comment: Не вижу причины использовать именно map

Comment: А какую структуру вы предложите?

Comment: Массив или список - ведь поиск по ключу здесь не требуется.

Comment: А сортировать?
или вы предлагаете просто сразу отсортированный массив ребер на вход подавать?

Comment: Вы ссылку на emaxx смотрели?